# nginx header variable escape special characters in header name

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I want to read a header in nginx.conf which has '-' in it

x-foo-bar

using $http_name

$http_x-foo-bar the value of the variable becomes "-foo-bar"

looks like its trying to find a header named x and then appending -foo-bar to the value

is there any way to escape these "-"s

I tried / but 
$http_x/-foo/-bar gives a value of /-foo/-bar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_):

> a variable name is the field name converted to lower case with dashes
>   replaced by underscores

Try:

```
$http_x_foo_bar
```